# Symfony3 fetch wrong data from database

Tags: jenkins, docker, doctrine, twig, symfony

I have a symfony 3 project that work fine on my local machine but in deploiyment on docker and after clearing cache and give 777 right to the var folder the project work but with wrong data.
this is the controler method for exemple:

> ```
> /**
>  * @Route("/post/index",name="postindex")
>  */
> public function indexAction()
> {
>     $Posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Post')->findAll();
>     return $this->render('AppBundle:Post:index.html.twig', array('posts' => $Posts));
> }
> ```

this is the twig template

```
> {% extends "::base.html.twig" %} {% block title %}List Post{% endblock
> %} {% block body %}
>     <section class="firstsection">
>         <div class="container">
>             <h2>Posts</h2>
>             <table class="table  table-bordered">
>                 <tr class="active">
>                     <td class="text-bold">Title</td>
>                     <td class="text-bold">Body</td>
>                     <td class="text-bold">created At</td>
>                     <td class="text-bold">update dAt</td>
>                     <td class="text-bold">Action</td>
>                 </tr>
>                 {% for post in posts %}
>                     <tr>
>                         <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
>                         <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
>                         <td>{{ post.createdAt|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
>                         <td>{{ post.updatedAt|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
>                         <td>
>                             <ul>
>                                 <li><a href="{{ path('postshow', {'id': post.id}) }}">View</a></li>
>                                 <li><a href="{{ path('postupdate', {'id': post.id}) }}">Edit</a></li>
>                                 <li><a href="{{ path('postdelete', {'id': post.id}) }}">Delete</a></li>
>                             </ul>
>                         </td>
>                     </tr>
>                 {% endfor %}
>             </table>
>         </div>
>     </section> {% endblock %}
```

this is the result:
[image]

and this is what i have in the post table

[image]

any help please? 
sorry for the english.

Comment: Do you mean the "title" and "body" show the wrong values? Maybe the order is ascending?

Comment: I did not really understand your problem. The data shown in both images are completely different!? What is actually stored in your DB in your deployed app? Do you want to order the elements by ID to have an ascending order of the given values in your 2nd screenshot?

Comment: @Alvinbunk no all my data is listed in the picture on php my admin.

Comment: @radon66 yes the problem is that the data shown in both images are completely different. i cleared the cache by :
 bin/console cache:clear -e=prod
and by
rm -rf var/cache/*

Comment: Can you confirm that the file `app/config/parameters.yml` shows a `database_name` which matches the screenshot you show from phpMyAdmin? My guess is you are using a different database.

Comment: `database_name` in `app/config/parameters.yml` contain a valid data.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a different database for the deployed version

Comment: No the same data base when i select the data from docker terminal i find the same data.